# Why is engine's speed slow at the start?

Tags: engines

I noticed that the nps (nodes per seconds) of different chess engines is very low at the start of the analysis and only after several seconds reaches is peak value. Does anybody have an explanation of this strange phenomenon?

Comment: Maybe the first positions encountered are fully evaluated, stored into cache, and then, when analyzing the following moves, position evaluations are retrieved from cache, but still counted as "positions evaluated".

Comment: I wouldn't discard the possibility that some chess engine programmers mean to mislead their competitors.
Maybe you'd want to post this same question in a specialized forum like talkchess.com

Comment: Sorry for the double comment. It seems in the forum I mentioned this topic has been treated more than once:
http://talkchess.com/forum/viewtopic.php?topic_view=threads&p=389052&t=37694

Answer (score 2):

Right after starting the analysis of a position the engine has to prepare the hash table in the memory or check it if there is one allready. You can verify this by giving your engine a low ammount of RAM (e.g. 32 MB). You will notice that the nps accelleration will go up. However, this heavyly will decrease the strength of the engine.